# Mapping a string and an enum to a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, enums

My function *foo* takes two parameters - a string *str*, and a strongly typed enum *ENUM1*. It is supposed to instantiate a class template whose template parameters depend on str and ENUM1. How do I achieve this without using multiple if..then..else statements as below?

```
void foo(std::string str, ENUM1 enumVal) {
    if (str == "str1" && enumVAL == ENUM1::VAL1)
           ExampleClass<STR1TYPE, VAL1TYPE> instance;
    else if (str == "str1" && enumVAL == ENUM1::VAL2)
           ExampleClass<STR1TYPE, VAL2TYPE> instance;
    else if (str == "str2" && enumVAL == ENUM1::VAL1)
           ExampleClass<STR2TYPE, VAL1TYPE> instance;
    ...
}
```

I cannot change how ExampleClass is designed and nor can I change the parameter types coming in. And I hate the if then else for all the permutations of the values for two parameters.

I was thinking of keeping an `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, ENUM>, ExampleClassBase>`, but that will mean taking up memory for saving readability of code.

Is there a niftier way of doing this?

Comment: Switching to an `unordered_map` just trades heap memory for code size - your current hard-coded approach results in extra executable size. One or the other may be slightly smaller but unless you are in a severely memory constrained environment the difference isn't something you should worry much about.

Comment: Actually memory footprint matters for me. So at the moment, I have implemented using if then elses and was looking for a smarter and more readable implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a small example of templates and type traits magic.

First - that function for single case will be great for you:

```
template <typename StrType, typename EnumType>
void fooSingleCase()
{
    std::cout << "In: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; 
    ExampleClass<StrType, EnumType> instance;
    // ...
}
```

If you need to have different code for different StrType/EnumType pairs - you can modify this a little:

```
template <typename StrType, typename EnumType>
void fooSingleCaseImplementation(ExampleClass<StrType, EnumType>& instance)
{
   // most default implementation
}
void fooSingleCaseImplementation(ExampleClass<STR1TYPE, VAL2TYPE>& instance)
{
   // some specific implementation
}


template <typename StrType, typename EnumType>
void fooSingleCase()
{
    std::cout << "In: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; 
    ExampleClass<StrType, EnumType> instance;
    fooSingleCaseImplementaction(instance);
}
```

---

But how to go from your `foo` to this `fooSingleCase`. First you need to connect types with values - you need type traits technique here:

```
template <typename StrType>
struct StrTraits
{
    static const std::string pattern;
}; 
template <typename EnumType>
struct ENUM1Traits
{
    static const ENUM1 pattern;
};
```

And the traits instances:

```
template <>
const std::string StrTraits<STR1TYPE>::pattern = "str1";
template <>
const std::string StrTraits<STR2TYPE>::pattern = "str2";

template <>
const ENUM1 ENUM1Traits<VAL1TYPE>::pattern = ENUM1::VAL1;
template <>
const ENUM1 ENUM1Traits<VAL2TYPE>::pattern = ENUM1::VAL2;
template <>
const ENUM1 ENUM1Traits<VAL3TYPE>::pattern = ENUM1::VAL3;
```

---

So - we are almost done. We need to make template magic now:

First - assume you already get EnumType - all you need is to select strType - so - start using traits:

```
template <typename EnumType>
void fooFixedEnumCase(std::string strVal)
{
    std::cout << strVal << " not found!\n";
}

template <typename EnumType, typename Str1Type, typename ...StrType>
void fooFixedEnumCase(std::string strVal)
{
    if (StrTraits<Str1Type>::pattern == strVal)
        fooSingleCase<EnumType, Str1Type>();
    else
        fooFixedEnumCase<EnumType, StrType...>(strVal);
}
```

For selecting enumType then strType - we need two set of variadic templates types - so let use class template with member function template:

```
template <typename ...EnumType>
struct Enum1Switch;

template <typename EnumType1, typename ...EnumType>
struct Enum1Switch<EnumType1, EnumType...>
{
    template <typename ...StrType>
    static void strSwitch(std::string str, ENUM1 enumVal)
    {
        if (ENUM1Traits<EnumType1>::pattern == enumVal)
            fooFixedEnumCase<EnumType1, StrType...>(str);
        else
            Enum1Switch<EnumType...>::template strSwitch<StrType...>(str, enumVal);
    }
};

template <>
struct Enum1Switch<>
{
    template <typename ...StrType>
    static void strSwitch(std::string str, ENUM1 enumVal)
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(enumVal) << " not found!\n";
    }
};
```

Then your foo will be as simple as this:

```
void foo(std::string str, ENUM1 enumVal) {

    Enum1Switch<VAL1TYPE, VAL2TYPE, VAL3TYPE>
        ::strSwitch<STR1TYPE, STR2TYPE>(str, enumVal);
}
```

An example in [ideone](http://ideone.com/O9ZRPz)

---

The question - how to extend this mechanism with new types. Like STRTYPENEW, VALTYPENEW. A few steps only needed:

New traits:

```
template <>
const std::string StrTraits<STRTYPENEW>::pattern = "newstr";
template <>
const ENUM1 ENUM1Traits<VALTYPENEW>::pattern = ENUM1::NEW_VAL;
```

And just a small change in foo:

```
void foo(std::string str, ENUM1 enumVal) {

    Enum1Switch<VAL1TYPE, VAL2TYPE, VAL3TYPE, VALTYPENEW>
    //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ::strSwitch<STR1TYPE, STR2TYPE, STRTYPENEW>(str, enumVal);
    //                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^  
}
```

---

One last comment - if you make all these functions inline - the code generated (I mean assembler code) for this template magic and your initial if/else approach is very much the same.